# Why am I getting the error, "undefined reference to `pow' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [p1] Error 1"?

Tags: c, makefile, math.h

Here is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc 

CFLAGS=-g

LDFLAGS=-lm

EXECS= p1


all: $(EXECS)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o $(EXECS)
```

14:32:16 **** Build of configuration Default for project CH3-Programs ****
make p1 
gcc  -g  -ggdb -lm  p1.c   -o p1
/tmp/ccNTyUSA.o: In function `main':
/home/bm5788/fromVM/Workspace/CH3-Programs//p1.c:28: undefined reference to`pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [p1] Error 1
: recipe for target 'p1' failed

Comment: And the makefile will build the executable `p1` from what object files? And please post the output from running the `make` command (after `make clean`).

Comment: Do you use pow function in your code?

Comment: Yes I used pow in my code.

Comment: Where would i find the object files?

Comment: I mean, you say that `all` depend on $(EXECS)` (i.e. `p1`). But what does `$(EXECS)` depend on?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would know. I am new to all of this.

Comment: I was told that as long as I have the -lm then it should link math.h.

Comment: in which folder do you have math.h and in which folder do you have your code

Comment: My code is in the folder 'CH3-Programs'

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the order you link with the math library (the `-lm` option). Libraries should be after the sources or object files on the command line when building.

So if you ran the command to build manually, it should look like

```
gcc p1.c -o p1 -lm
```

The problem is that your makefile doesn't really do anything, and it lives on *implicit* rules alone. The implicit rules use certain variables in a certain order which do not place the library in the right position in your makefile.

Try instead something like this makefile:

```
# The C compiler to use.
CC = gcc

# The C compiler flags to use.
# The -g flag is for adding debug information.
# The -Wall flag is to enable more warnings from the compiler
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

# The linker flags to use, none is okay.
LDFLAGS = 

# The libraries to link with.
LDLIBS = -lm

# Define the name of the executable you want to build.
EXEC = p1

# List the object files needed to create the executable above.
OBJECTS = p1.o

# Since this is the first rule, it's also the default rule to make
# when no target is specified. It depends only on the executable
# being built.
all: $(EXEC)

# This rule tells make that the executable being built depends on
# certain object files. This will link using $(LDFLAGS) and $(LDLIBS).
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)

# No rule needed for the object files. The implicit rules used
# make together with the variable defined above will make sure
# they are built with the expected flags.

# Target to clean up. Removes the executable and object files.
# This target is not really necessary but is common, and can be
# useful if special handling is needed or there are many targets
# to clean up.
clean:
    -rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
```

If you run `make` using the above makefile, the `make` program should first build the object file `p1.o` from the source file `p1.c`. Then is should use the `p1.o` object file to link the executable `p1` together with the standard math library.

Comment: Yes!! It worked! Thank you very much. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @BryceMarshall You can thank the answerer more effectively by upvoting and accepting his answer :-)